# What should I use, locale route or declare it in my routes.yaml?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am new in symfony 4 and trying to study it.  Right now Im doing the navigation bar linking my home, about etc and crud. I am confused when should I use the locale route or routes.yaml. The tutorials Im watching right now uses the locale route, and last night used the routes.yaml.

Question:  What or when should I use, locale route or declare it in my routes.yaml? Is there any advantage or disadvantage?

Example: If I have a button for creating new item

Should I use this:

**VIEW**

```
<a href="{{ path("new_page")}} "><button class="btn btn-success">New Item</button></a>
```

Or this one

```
<a href="/item/new"><button class="btn btn-success">New Item</button></a>
```

**My routes.yaml**

```
# new_page:
#    path: /item/new
#    controller: App\Controller\ItemController::new
```

Comment: use ```path```. the advantage is obvious: when url pattern is changed, route are regenerated by ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i was you, i should use the path. Because it makes your code more dynamic. If you later decide to change the URLs. It will automatically use the new route.

```
new_page:
   path: /item/new
   controller: App\Controller\ItemController::new
```

can be easily change to:

```
new_page:
   path: /item/newer
   controller: App\Controller\ItemController::new
```

You only need to change the path in the routing config. All the views can stay the same. path('new_page')